# OpenTripPlanner (Error: 406) No transit times available

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, general-transit-feed-specification, opentripplanner

I try using OpenTripPlanner to create a webmap with multimodal routing function.

I followed the instruction on: http://opentripplanner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Basic-Usage/

1. I downloaded `otp-1.1.0-shaded.jar` from: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/opentripplanner/otp/
2. I grabbed GTFS data from: https://code.google.com/archive/p/googletransitdatafeed/wikis/PublicFeeds.wiki (download for Berlin:  http://www.vbb.de/de/datei/gtfs-daten.zip)
3. Also got latest osm.pbf file from: http://download.geofabrik.de/ (download for Berlin: http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/berlin-latest.osm.pbf)
4. Started the local server with: `java -Xmx2G -jar otp-1.1.0-shaded.jar --build C:/user/name/otp --inMemory`,
   whereas `berlin-gtfs.zip` and `berlin-osm.pbf` are located in `C:/user/name/otp`

The server is starting and I can access the map via http://localhost:8080/
But when I want to use the routing function for transit, it always gives me the following error:

> No transit times available. The date may be past or too far in the
>   future or there may not be transit service for your trip at the time
>   you chose. (Error 406)

My thoughts are that the GTFS data are somehow broken or not useable for OpenTripPlanner.

So I used the GTFS Feed Validator (https://github.com/google/transitfeed/wiki/FeedValidator)

**The Results of the GTFS FeedValidator:**

- Agencies: Verkehrsverbund Brandenburg-Berlin, ...
- Routes: 1363
- Stops: 12845
- Trips: 204915
- Shapes: 0
- Effective: June 06, 2013 to December 14, 2013

Found these problems:
19528 warnings

- 87 Duplicate IDs
- 1 Expiration Date
- 1810 Invalid Values
- 5313 Overlapping Trips In Same Blocks
- 5 Stops Too Closes
- 12310 Too Fast Travels
- 2 Unrecognized Columns

Comment: Maybe the zip file is in the wrong format (https://github.com/opentripplanner/OpenTripPlanner/issues/1375). Try to extract and re-create it.

Comment: unfortunately it's not that. Extracted and reacreated it, still doesn't work. I used the GTFS validation for feeder and added the result to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occured because the GTFS data from: https://code.google.com/archive/p/googletransitdatafeed/wikis/PublicFeeds.wiki are **out of date**. Which also can be seen in the GTFS Feed Validater:

> Effective: June 06, 2013 to December 14, 2013

Once downloaded the data for the year 2017 the problem didn't occur anymore. (Source: https://daten.berlin.de/kategorie/verkehr)